# Javascript render object of arrays as table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have a JavaScript object in which I am trying to render as a table, though I am unable to figure out how to access each individual array.

Here is a sample of the object (defLogTable):

```
{
    "headings": [
        "Item",
        "Equip Tag",
        "Ref#",
        "Description",
        "Corrective Action Taken or Date Completed"
    ],
    "values": [
        [
            1,
            "RTU-1",
            1,
            "This did not work",
            "Make it Work"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "EF-1",
            2,
            "This also didn't work",
            "Make this one work too"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Each 'values' array corresponds to a row in the table.

And What I have tried:

```
<table className="def-tbl">
                    <tbody>
                        {console.log(defLogTable)}
                        {defLogTable.headings.map(heading => (
                            <th>{heading}</th>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headings')

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using some kind of JavaScript framework here? If not, none of this will work (you can't put curly braces in ordinary HTML and have anything magical happen).

Comment: This is React JSX, syntax-wise everything is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested `map` to render each row in the `values` property.

```
<table className="def-tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {defLogTable.headings.map(heading => (
        <th>{heading}</th>
      ))}
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    {defLogTable.values.map(row => (
      <tr>
        {row.map(cell => (
          <td>{cell}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is what I currently have, I receive the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headings')

Comment: So your `defLogTable` value is `undefined`. Probably because the initial state of `defLogTable` is not the object that you show in your question, but `undefined`. Just check if `defLogTable` is `undefined ` before rendering the table.

Comment: I never thought that would be the case since I was able to console.log() it, but adding a simple 'defLogTable &&' worked like a charm, thank you sir